# Errand of Mercy, Minute 38

Tags: star-trek

Who was that man dressed in a blue, short-sleeve shirt walking across the bridge behind Sulu at minute 38:59?  Was that a mistake or can the crew wear something different from the typical uniforms while on duty?

[image]

Comment: I believe I found the image you were talking about, although I have it 10 minutes later in the same episode.  Feel free to roll it back if I've picked the wrong one. (He comes out of the lift and walks to screen right, while Spock goes the other way.)  If it is the right image, it's a Sciences Jumpsuit, as Izkata mentions in his answer.

Comment: @KHW Mine was as well, my guess is that Sarah saw a modern TV cut that's only ~40 minutes long (making more room for commercials by removing content)

Answer (score 8):

It's not a mistake; that's a [sciences division duty jumpsuit](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_(mid_2260s-early_2270s)#Duty_jumpsuit):

[image: Crewmember in blue jumpsuit]
<sup>(Image appears to be from 1x06, [The Naked Time](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Naked_Time_(episode)))</sup>

From the uniform page linked above:

> Everyday work jumpsuits were also worn, usually with no assignment or rank patches visible (even if the jumpsuit was worn by a senior officer). Duty jumpsuits come in a division color. Some versions had embroidered writing and insignia on the left breast. The jumpsuit had medium length sleeves and was worn open in the front, sealing at the waistline. A standard black undershirt was worn underneath, in contrast with jumpsuit uniforms of the previous style with division-colored undershirts. The jumpsuits came in red (operations division), green/brown (command division) and blue (sciences division). (TOS: "The Naked Time", "The Enemy Within", "Mudd's Women", "Balance of Terror", "Dagger of the Mind")